# Database recovery procedure

Tags: sql-server, restore

I recovered a database with last full backup, all differentials after the full, and then all log backups after the last differential.

Can I trust the database is right or do I have to do it again the right way: with full, then *last* differential, then all transaction backups after that?

Comment: If series of backup is being able to bring database to consistent state it means database is in consistent state. Barring corrupt backup. I dont understand what you mean by *Can I trust the database is right*. Query the database and see if you can find your data. This would be best test

Comment: I mean if the data is ok. I have checked dB with dbcc checkdb and no errors.

Comment: To check data is OK you have to run various select queries and see for yourself. Or you can compare data using various tools. but I guess running queries and accessing application would tell you

Answer (score 1):

No, you dont have to do it again.

The differential backups are just that so the only effect your mistake made was to make the restore time longer than neccessary. If your last transaction log backup was restored successfully then you are ok.

Comment: Good to hear :) Thanks for your time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before restoring the backups if you are following the practise of verifying the backups that are taken as mentioned above, like full diff and log, it makes sense that after successful restore you should be good.

However, you also need to be sure on the time between those full diff and log backups. So unless until there is no chain broken between them, you should be good here.

Also,  would suggest you to run `DBCC CHECKDB` on the database

CHECKDB will at least tell you if your DB has any consistency errors, and checks the logical and physical integrity of all the objects in the specified DB